# DCOM got error "2147942405" from the computer x.x.x.x when attempting to activate the server:

Tags: opc, dcom

I have a program on my computer that runs as SYSTEM and it is trying to launch an exe(opc server) on a remote machine x.x.x.x. But I get a DCOM error in my machine's eventviewer.

```
DCOM got error "2147942405" from the computer x.x.x.x when attempting to activate the server: yyyyy
```

I followed almost all the suggestions on the internet about opening dcomcnfg and adding users limits.default for launch and activation and  Everyone,system,interactive,network from link (ftp://ftp.softing.com/pub/outgoing/opc/DCOM/DCOM-Settings-en.pdf) but nothing works.

Would anybody have nay other ideas on how to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

According to MS Technet:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/8bb5807f-73ba-4092-abc8-283d8fced6c4/request-a-certificate-from-certificate-service-fails-dcom-error-2147942405?forum=winserversecurity

With my VERY limited understanding of Certificate servers you may have one of the scenarios:

1. Client PC's are trying to connect to a Certificate server that no longer exists
2. Client PC's have a certificate that is valid but the Certificate server no longer exists
3. A Certificate server is broken
4. Clients do not have the proper authority to request the Certificate

I say this is limited knowledge as I am currently trying to remove AD Certificate services from a Domain Controller and I can see that in the System event log the exact same messages are being logged as I have stopped the Certificate services to asses the impact.  If I get further information I will post back.